# android 2.2 and 2.3

Tags: android

why android 2.2 phones not upgradeable to 2.3? Is there any hardware requirement?

Comment: They are. They will just not be able to take use of some new features like NFC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Who says they are not? A lot of them are. The manufacturer just have to release the code. In parallel once the code drops into the Android Open Source Project (has not happened yet) many custom roms like cynaogen will adapt it as well.